# How to prove the accuracy of an iso file built with dd from a DVD

Tags: iso, dd, dvd

I am trying to archive a data DVD that came with my scanner and am unable to get an exact copy.  An iso file of a DVD burned from the iso file of the original DVD is LARGER.

Copy errors do not account for the problem.  Everything I have tried has been repeated and proven reproducible.  Many references imply that the dd command is indifferent to formatting schemes and can therefore (I think) be used to duplicate optical media, audio CDs being an exception.

The following commands have been run both in my account and as root (superuser) with no difference.  (Fedora 30)

With the original DVD in the drive:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=origDVD.iso bs=1024
cat origDVD.iso        |sha512sum >sha512sum.origDVDiso.txt
dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=1024 |sha512sum >sha512sum.origDVDdsk.txt
```

Put blank DVD in the drive and burn it from origDVD.iso

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=origDVD.iso
```

Close the drawer with the copied DVD in the drive:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=copyDVD.iso bs=1024
cat copyDVD.iso        |sha512sum >sha512sum.copyDVDiso.txt
dd if=/dev/sr0 bs=1024 |sha512sum >sha512sum.copyDVDdsk.txt
```

- Results

  - MATCH (as expected):

    - sha512sum.origDVDiso.txt AND sha512sum.origDVDdsk.txt
    - sha512sum.copyDVDiso.txt AND sha512sum.copyDVDdsk.txt
  - DO NOT MATCH (which is the mystery I need help to understand):

    - origDVD.iso AND copyDVD.iso
    - sha512sum.origDVDiso.txt AND sha512sum.copyDVDiso.txt
    - sha512sum.origDVDdsk.txt AND sha512sum.copyDVDdsk.txt
  - iso file Sizes

    - origDVD.iso  2348851200
    - copyDVD.iso  2348875776

The copied DVD mounts and appears to function correctly even though it is provably different from the original.

Comment: (Captcha does not let me post answers, only comments.)
Surplus size is normal with DVD. Only DVD-R[W] written with DAO are
guaranteed to end at the payload end (growisofs option
-use-the-force-luke=dao). Use dd option count= to copy only
the size of the original ISO image. 2348851200 : bs=2048 count=1146900 .
If no original size is known, use command /sbin/isosize (divided by 2048).

Comment: Your "comment" is in fact an answer. Thank you. "Surplus size is normal with DVD" was key to improving my rudimentary understanding of iso files.  I used diff -r to successfully compare a loop mounted iso file from a copied DVD to the original disk.   Incidentally, if I use isosize as you suggest (or isoinfo to save doing the arithmetic) to get values for the dd count and bs arguments, then the iso file from the original DVD is only 985,743,360 bytes (instead of 2,348,851,200).

Comment: (Answering by comment is cumbersome, indeed.) isosize gives the size claim of
the filesystem. dd, if not curbed, gives the readable size of the device.
The difference in your case is very large, but still much too low for a
fully formatted DVD+RW or DVD-RAM. So if this is a factory-made DVD-ROM,
then there is something else stored after the ISO filesystem.
If it is a DVD+RW then it might be partially formatted and you read just
remaining stuff from a previous larger data payload.

Comment: My original was a factory DVD-ROM so "there is something else stored after the ISO filesystem."  Is that something that has utility or just random stuff?  I.e. does the factory disk have capability that I cannot archive?  I am frankly disappointed if I need to learn a bunch of arcane file system details;  I (naively?) thought that the dd command and iso files provided freedom from that.

Comment: Hard to say what is in the 1.3 GB of data after the end of the ISO filesystem.
Whatever, your uncurbed dd copy is supposed to have put it into the disk
file and your burn run is supposed to have put it onto the copied DVD.
If the SHA512 of original DVD and copied DVD (curbed to the originally
readable size) match, then you have copied the DVD content successfully. 
(There are non-content properties, though, which do not get copied. E.g.
a DVD-ROM can have a serial number.)

Comment: @Thomas  I do not understand how captcha is standing between us, but at the risk of violating some rule, thank you very much for your assistance.  However, just when I think I have some measure of understanding...  I tried a 2nd DVD the content files of which are listed in uppercase.  The contents of the iso file are lowercase.  Using the dd conv=ucase or conv=lcase makes no difference.  I also used the cat command e.g. cat /dev/sr0 >dks.iso. The SHA512 hashes of the iso files match each other but not the disk.  I am completely baffled.

Comment: (There is captcha test against robots when posting answers. My browser is 
too old for it. So i cannot post answers.)
Your new problem would be a new question. The answer will probably need
some experiments on your side. We may discuss this by mail, if you want.
In private: scdbackup@gmx.net . Publicly: bug-xorriso@gnu.org .